# Factory for contextvar default value

Tags: python, python-contextvars

Setting a dictionary as `ContextVar` default:

```py
var: ContextVar[dict] = ContextVar('var', default={})
```

...kinda works, as the dictionary will be available as default, but it always references the same instance, instead of generating a new one for each context.

Do contextvars somehow support factories (for dicts, lists, and alike), as in:

```py
var: ContextVar[dict] = ContextVar('var', default=list)
var: ContextVar[dict] = ContextVar('var', default=lambda: dict())
```

Or do I just have to do it manually:

```py
var: ContextVar[Optional[dict]] = ContextVar('var', default=None)

...

if not var.get():
    var.set({})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently ContextVars designed choice was in the direction of providing the low level, barebones, functionality over ease of use.

There is no easy way to get a context-aware namespace, as you intend to do by having the dictionary as default. And also, no option for the default value to use a factory rather than a single object.

The only way to overcome that is to write a class that provides a higher level interface on top of contextvars (or other context-separating mechanism).

I am just working on such a package, although I made no release yet - y main goal is to have a class that act as a free-to-use namespace, just like threading.Local instances. (There is also one class using the mapping interface) - if I get more people using and providing some feedback, I could come faster to a finished form:

https://github.com/jsbueno/extracontext

Comment: I guess needs to be the accepted answer then - if factories / custom initializers are not supported, they are not supported. Will look into your package .

Comment: The package does not feature factories for defaults right now, but give me a word if you find it interesting - it is somewhat on the TODO list with "descriptor-like" defaults - with those I can have default factories.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Google's wrapper around `contextvar`: https://github.com/google/etils/blob/main/etils/edc/README.md#wrap-fields-around-contextvar for a dataclass-like API:

Any dataclass is supported:

- To make a field context-dependent: annotate the field with `edc.ContextVar[T]`.
- To have a factory as default value, use: `dataclasses.field(default_factory=)`

```py
from etils import edc

@edc.dataclass
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Context:
  thread_id: edc.ContextVar[int] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=threading.get_native_id)

  # Local stack: each thread will use its own instance of the stack
  stack: edc.ContextVar[list[str]] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)


# Global context object
context = Context(thread_id=0)
```

Each threads/task will have it's own version of the field:

```py
def worker():
  # Inside each thread, the worker use its own context
  assert context.thread_id != 0
  context.stack.append(1)
  time.sleep(1)
  assert len(context.stack) == 1  # Other workers do not modify the local stack

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
  for _ in range(10):
    executor.submit(worker)
```